# How to cache a query result for several minutes in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query like this:

```
profiles = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('-created')
```

There are several thousands of userprofiles hence the query is costly. so I am wondering how to cache the result for 5 minutes.

I have read [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/optimization/) but could not find my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) instead.

In essence, django's querysets are lazy and their maintain a cache, meaning they only call the db when evaluated for the first time. This means that your `profile` variable will only query the db once during it's lifetime (unless you do `profile.filter()` or something similar to alter the query in which case it will have to be reevaluated).

Now the important part in regards to your question is the lifetime of the variable. It will go out of scope as soon as the method it is defined in returns, in other words it will be created anew, querying the db, for each new request. In order to avoid that you can either cache the results using [memcached](http://memcached.org) or a similar system *OR* by making your `profile` variable global which will persist between requests.

Comment: I've read those and added `memcache` as my caching backend (and installed python-mechace and memcache) but it does not seem to have any effect to speed up the query rendering. Also when I add `@cache_page(60 * 5)` decorator to the views, I get 500 error.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your seutp. Try getting a minimal example to work using memcache and use something like `time.sleep(4)` to simulate a slow query to easier tell if you're getting the desired effect.